# What's the difference between copying a list then appending an element, and appending to the original list in python

Tags: python, recursion

I have been solving a problem using dynamic programming and spent hours debugging and the bug wasn't obvious until I converted the code to another language. In the code below,

```
# given a target sum and a list of numbers, find the
# smallest combination that yields the target sum
def bestSum(target, num, memo={}):     # line 1
    if target in memo:
        return memo[target]
    if target < 0:
        return None                    # line 5
    if target == 0:
        return []
    else:
        best_sum = None
        for i in range(len(num)):      # line 10
            remainder = bestSum(target - num[i], num, memo)
            if remainder != None:
                remainder = [r for r in remainder]     # line 13
                remainder.append(num[i])               # line 14
                #remainder.append(num[i])              # line 15
                if best_sum == None or len(remainder) < len(best_sum):
                    best_sum = remainder
        #end for
        memo[target] = best_sum
        return best_sum
#end def

# to test the function
print(bestSum(100, [25, 5], memo={}))
```

How does the code behave between the 2 options below:

1. if i have lines 13 and 14 active (line 15 commented) - this works
2. if i have line 15 active (lines 13 and 14 commented) - this doesnt work

They both seem to do the same thing however the final result of the function is completely different.

In either of the options, the resulting list shouldn't be same? Line 11 will give a brand new list and then in option 1, I'm just copying the whole list again and adding the new element to it. In option 2, I'm just adding to the same list. I don't understand why they aren't the same.

Comment: The problem isn't actually lines 13, 14, 15.. the issue you are dealing with is that python passes lists by reference instead of by value. So when you use line 15 you are referencing the list that was passed into the function. When you use 13, 14 you are making a new list from the values (so essentially mimicking pass by value).

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim python **never** uses pass by reference as an evaluation strategy, and it only ever uses one evaluation strategy, it isn't different for different types. It uses *neither* call by reference nor call by value.

Comment: To over-simplify things, one could say lists are accessed “by reference” in Python. (Everything is, sort of, but some types behave like “implicitly existing immutable singletons” (~ “scalars”) and some don’t.) Making a deep copy (e.g. `remainder = remainder[:]`) adds a new list to your `memo` dictionary whereas appending to an existing list will modify that existing list and (re-)reference it, possibly multiple times under different keys, in `memo`. Which may become a mess. [Make sure you read this too.](https://newbedev.com/why-is-the-empty-dictionary-a-dangerous-default-value-in-python)

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek not sort of. Everything has reference semantics in Python, although, that isn't the same as call by reference as an evaluation strategy, which Python absolutely never supports. Note, using slice notation doesn't create a deep copy, but a shallow copy (which is all that is needed here anyway)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, sure… The Python terminology is quite odd due to way too many incompatibilities with (somewhat more) common C/C++/Java/JS terminology, most of which don’t bring any extra benefits or interesting insights. Anyway, my “sort of” was referring to (e.g.) the fact that `a = 5; b = 5; a is b` yields `True` whereas `a = [5]; b = [5]; a is b` is `False`. The latter is not surprising at all. The former shows, however, that despite all the object-reference-like technicalities, the way the `5` “works” is not so different from the `5` known from many/most other languages.

Comment: And just to make your code more Python looking.  Line 13 could also be written as `remainder = remainder[:]` or `remainder = remainder.copy()`.  Both make it clearer that you're taking a copy.  No need for list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you all for the clarifications and advice. Just to point out, the same happens in javascript. 
remainder = [...remainder, num[i]]; works, and
remainder .push(num[i]); doesnt work